# Remove repeated occurence of string

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a method that will only remove the first repeat occurence that is attached to the first.

For instance this:

```
removedup("user@gmail.com@gmail.com", "@gmail.com")
```

Should produce this

```
@gmail.com
```

Comment: I think you are expecting to produce this `user@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

```
"user@gmail.com@gmail.com".gsub(/(@gmail\.com)+/, '\1')
```